# Can't access fields inside variables from ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ejs

I've made this simple app based on mongodb and express. I'm trying to display an array inside an ejs page, but only some parameters from the array's objects. Currently it's either not showing anything or showing the entire json object, depending on my tries.

Here is the relevant part from my controller:

```
query.exec(function (err, countries){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return next(err);
        }
        countries.sort((a, b) => {
           return a.toString().localeCompare(b.toString());
        });
        console.log(countries);
        res.render('pages/index',{
            countries: countries
        });
```

And my ejs code with nothing shown

```
<select class="form-control" id="countriesSelect" name="country">
                        <% countries.forEach(function(country) { %>
                        <option><%= country.Age %></option>
                            <% }); %>
                    </select>
```

The console log is fine:

```
[ { Country: 'Albania', Age: 18 },   
  { Country: 'Algeria', Age: 18 },   
  { Country: 'Andorra', Age: 18 },   
  { Country: 'Argentina', Age: 17 }, 
  { Country: 'Australia', Age: 16 }, 
  { Country: 'Austria', Age: 18 },   
  { Country: 'Azerbaijan', Age: 18 },
  { Country: 'Bahamas', Age: 17 },   
  { Country: 'Bahrain', Age: 18 },   
  { Country: 'Belarus', Age: 18 },
  { Country: 'Belgium', Age: 18 },
  { Country: 'Bolivia', Age: 18 },
  { Country: 'Bosnia and Herzegovina', Age: 18 },
  { Country: 'Brazil', Age: 18 },
  { Country: 'Bulgaria', Age: 18 },
  { Country: 'Cambodia', Age: 18 },
  { Country: 'Canada', Age: 16 },
  { Country: 'Chile', Age: 17 },
  { Country: 'China', Age: 18 },
  { Country: 'Colombia', Age: 16 }
...
```

Here is a screenshot from the page:
[image: screenshot]

I want in the combobox to be displayed only the country names. (country.Country) for example "Algeria" "America"

PS: I know it's bad naming, I will refactor my database.

PSS: I'm new to ejs and node so this is quite hard for me to debug. Sorry if it's a trivial question

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:** We have to convert `country` to become a JSON object before accessing its property `.Age`. Credit to [@Filip Tepes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4885222/filip-tepes)

There is a typo `<option> <%= country.Age %> </li>`

It supposes to be `<option> <%= country.toJSON().Age %> </option>`

```
<select class="form-control" id="countriesSelect" name="country">
    <% countries.forEach(function(country) { %>
        <option><%= country.toJSON().Age %></li> // <------ this line
    <% }); %>
</select>
```

Comment: ups, fixed that. But it's still the same

Comment: looks like we need to do a `.toJSON()` on the country object

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix. I should have added .toJson to get the actual object.

Here is the fix:

```
<select class="form-control" id="countriesSelect" name="country">
                    <% countries.forEach(function(country) { %>
                    <option><%= country.toJSON().Country %></option>
                        <% }); %>
                </select>
```